Replacing Old Mid-Circuit Porch Receptacle w/ GFCI
Need to replace old porch receptacle with GFCI. The outlet is mid-stream of the circuit & circuit also protected by AFCI breaker in the sub-panel. The last outlet downstream from patio outlet powers the garage freezer. Since the entire circuit has AFCI protection, is it necessary to wire GFCI using LINE & LOAD terminals to cover all downstream outlets, or just use LINE connection to only protect that patio outlet?

If you want GFCI protection of the downstream outlets and receptacles, wire using the LINE and LOAD. If you don't want GFCI protection of the downstream, wire using only the LINE terminals. AFCI isn't really related as it protects against different things. Given that it's a freezer downstream, I'd be tempted to not GFCI protect it to avoid nuisance trips.
You have the option because you are fixing an existing circuit. If you were adding or extending a circuit then the garage receptacle would require GFCI protection since current and several recent code cycles require GFCIs anywhere that can be damp.

It would also be possible to disregard the "load" terminals at the porch GFCI receptacle, but put separate GFCI(s) at the downstream location(s). That way, everything would have protection but without the risk of, say, outdoor holiday lights getting wet and cutting off power to the freezer.

So that would mean pig-tailing each each receptacle using only the line terminals?

Yes, exactly that. That's how my kitchen is wired so that nuisance trips don't knock out the whole countertop. It means more money in GFCIs but in exchange you get more versatility.
